# pubnub webrtc android demo app showing "user is not online"

Tags: android, webrtc, pubnub

I have been trying to create my own pubnub webrtc video chat app, I have been using pubnub webrtc app for reference and it is working with the default pub and sub key, but when I use my own pub and sub key it shows that the user is not online.

Android Example app link - https://github.com/pubnub/AndroidRTC
Tutorial - http://realtimeweekly.co/android-webrtc-tutorial-pubnub/

```
public void dispatchCall(final String callNum){
    final String callNumStdBy = callNum + Constants.STDBY_SUFFIX;
    this.mPubNub.hereNow(callNumStdBy, new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void successCallback(String channel, Object message) {
            Log.d("MA-dC", "HERE_NOW: " +" CH - " + callNumStdBy + " " + message.toString());
            try {
                int occupancy = ((JSONObject) message).getInt(Constants.JSON_OCCUPANCY);
                if (occupancy == 0) {
                    showToast("User is not online!");
                    return;
                }
```

Comment: Hi @RDB did our answer help solve your issue?

Answer (score 0):

## Adding Presence to your WebRTC Mobile App

> https://admin.pubnub.com - login to your account and enable PRESENCE.

Sometimes you want to tell when a user is ONLINE or OFFLINE.  You want to know when other users come ONLINE, and you want to know when they go OFFLINE.  This is known as **Presence Detection**.

You can enable Presence Detection visiting https://admin.pubnub.com and navigating to your App Keys.  Then click on the Presence switch turning it ON.  This switch can be found under the Add-ons section.

[image: Presence WebRTC App]

See the example screenshot above.  You can see the ON switch is set.  This enabled Presence Detection for your mobile WebRTC App.